# android automatic title on red marker on Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a android map application where  it track the user location and display it on the map. i make it so that there will be a title "you are here" that appear on top of the red marker. however, it did not appear on its own and i must tap on the red marker. and i could tap on any red marker and the title would move there and disappear on the previous one.

how do i make it so that it only appears on the latest red marker(latest location) on its own and cannot be removed?to show the user his current location.

the speed i set it at 1.  i do not know whether it is good enough. the location stopped updating while i was not moving but it is still slow and inaccurate.

```
    public void onLocationChanged(Location myLocation) {
    System.out.println("speed " + myLocation.getSpeed());
    if(myLocation.getSpeed() > speed)
    {
        //show location on map.................
        //Get latitude of the current location
        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
        //Get longitude of the current location
        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
        //Create a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        //Show the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        //Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).snippet("You are here!").title("You are here!"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:-

```
Marker pos = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).snippet("You are here!").title("You are here!"));
```

instead of

```
   googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).snippet("You are here!").title("You are here!"));
```

Or
Write this, it is very easy:-

```
locationMarker.showInfoWindow();
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply. it works and i add    Marker pos = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).snippet("You are here!").title("You are here!"));
   pos.showInfoWindow();. it show what i want. thank you so much

Comment: its ok.. :)
pleasure.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't really achieve this by using the existing API's on Android, without coding a lot of custom views and controls.

There's a nice library which you can use to customize the markers on your maps. Here's an example taken from it's website. It's called ***android-maps-utils***

[image]

**The link to the library on github.**

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

**And the website, where you can find a video and other examples.**

http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/